# Exclude Vue Component from stylesheet of existing application

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js, less

We build a Vue component(using vuetify) into an existing .net MVC application.
The application loads the webpack into a `div`. 
The problem is that the vue component inherits all the CSS of the existing application. 
A simplified HTML version looks like this:

```
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>
    ...
    <div class="VUE_CLASS">
        //vue component...
    </div>
    ...
</body>
</html>
```

The Style is written in css.less.

I tried to exclude the `VUE_CLASS` from all CSS Rules of the existing application by applying a `:not(.VUE_CLASS)` and a `div:not(.VUE_CLASS)`. I also tried to wrap it around all rules in the css.less:

```
*:not(.VUE_CLASS){
//...css rules of the existing application
}
```

It doesn't work

I read about some other strategies (https://kloudless.com/blog/2019/02/05/creating-a-reusable-vuetify-component-to-use-in-other-apps/). Using an `iframe` is not an option because we can't access our backed from an iframe. I can't use Web components as well, because we have to support ie11.

Is it possible to exclude the `div` and all its child elements using less?

Thank you & Best regards,

Finn

Answer (score 0):

What if you just reset all CSS styles for `VUE_CLASS` selector?

Try adding this rule at the end of the `<style>` tag:

```css
.VUE_CLASS {
  all: unset !important;
  /* Write the other styles for this component below */
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Unfortunately, this doesn't work for all my classes in the in .VUE_CLASS.

Comment: @finnk what if you add `*` symbol so it applies to all children elements: `.VUE_CLASS * { ...` does that work?

Comment: .VUE_CLASS *{all: unset !important} , works, but it "unsets" all CSS rules from my Vue Component as well.

Comment: @finnk add your own styles after that rule, this way it will unset everything and then apply your own styles below that, also try removing `!important`. Other than that, I'm not really sure what else can be done to solve this problem